# Integration for Vaxin Security and Joomla?

Tags: security, joomla

I would like to use Vaxin Security on a Joomla site.

I use it for my WordPress sites and using the plugin they providing.
Will it work as well with Joomla?
How can i integrate it?

Comment: I suggest that you ask this question on the stack exchange site specifically for joomla [joomla.se]

Comment: As far as I know, Vaxin Security isn't available for Joomla.  Two good Joomla options you could consider are https://extensions.joomla.org/extension/admin-tools/ (free and commercial versions)  and https://extensions.joomla.org/extension/rsfirewall/ (commercial). You'll find more at https://extensions.joomla.org/tags/site-security/